# Where can I find a Powerline Internet Adapter with DIN Rail Mounting?

Tags: electrical

There are several products in the market to create a home LAN using the existing electrical wiring at home. In all of them the point of entry(or the emitter) is a device that is connected to a wall plug. What I'm trying to find is an emitter that can be mounted on the main electrical board, next to the circuit breakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT

[I found it!](http://www.elektro-wandelt.de/index.php?cl=details&anid=ea54ec9a62a583d74.43605988) 
Just search for `DEVOLO DLAN DIN`

[image]

EDIT

[Something like this](http://news.thomasnet.com/fullstory/Ethernet-Network-Terminals-are-offered-in-11-models-557464) but not sure if it exactly waht you want.
[image]

The only way is going to be to hack them and do waht you want. I have not seen anything like this for DIN.. even though i thought of it so many times.. because it makes sense. It will have to be something [like this.](http://www.easydaq.biz/PagesUSB/USB4PRSRMxFRAME.htm)

[image]

Essentially you will need to put one of these([below](http://www.electronics123.com/s.nl/it.A/id.3256/.f)) in that (above)..

[image]

[But I did find this on Search Engine](http://www.codico.com/en/news/impulse/detail/artikel/efficient-ethernet-networking-with-devolo-dlanR-power-line-communication-din-rail-adapter/)